# Assemble a JTS Polygon directly from an array of doubles?

Tags: java, matlab, jts

**Is there a performant way to assemble a JTS Polygon directly from an array of doubles?**

Currently, I am

1. Looping through array of points to create an array of `Coordinate` instances
2. Creating a `CoordinateSequence` from the array of `Coordinate`s
3. Creating a `LinearRing` from the `CoordinateSequence`
4. Creating a `Polygon` from the `LinearRing`

According to my profiling, the slowest step by far is creating the many `Coordinate` instances in loop.

I should mention I am calling the JTS library from Matlab, so there may be some extra cost incurred in my loop when compared to a pure Java implementation.

Here is the MATLAB code:

```
% assemble linear ring for exterior poly
[numExtPoints, ~] = size(exteriorCoords);
jExtCoords(numExtPoints) = jts.geom.Coordinate(); % pre-allocate
for ic = 1:numExtPoints
    jExtCoords(ic) = jts.geom.Coordinate(exteriorCoords(ic,1), exteriorCoords(ic,2));
end

jCoordinateSequence = jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequence(jExtCoords);
jExtLinearRing = jts.geom.LinearRing(jCoordinateSequence, jts.geom.GeometryFactory());

% build polygon 
obj.jGeometry = jts.geom.Polygon(jExtLinearRing, [], jts.geom.GeometryFactory());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this constructor:

`public Polygon polygon(double... ord)`

from

`org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryBuilder` ([Documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/jts/GeometryBuilder.html#polygon-double...-))

Example:

```
Polygon p = new GeometryBuilder().polygon(new double[]{0,0,10,0,10,10});
```